# Inductance value for ceiling/pedestal 230/240Vac single phase ac fans

Tags: inductance-measurement

I need to know how to roughly get idea about indcutance value of ceiling pedestal single phase AC fan?
I want to roughly model this.

Answer (score 1):

The overall inductance value of an induction motor –as typically used in ceiling fans– heavily depends on the slip.

At near synchronous speed (slip → 0), it's dominated by the field winding and for a 230V ceiling fan motor, roughly in the range of 300mH.

At standstill (slip → 1) it's dominated by the air gap and rotor magnetization which leads to an inductance of roughly 30mH.

Comment: If I could upvote this twice, I would. “It depends”, “Why”, “read the datasheet” and “ask the manufacturer” are the usual but way less helpful answers here. When I was in university a fellow student of mine called a transformer manufacturer to get a good approximation of the nominal efficiency of a 1 MVA transformer. “It depends on what you design for” didn’t help him.

Comment: @Janka  ,thankyou very much for your valuable feedback...can i know resistance value of fan motor as well?

Comment: The equivalent resistance depends on the torque and thus power the motor has to overcome due to the mounted fan. So P=U²/R → R=U²/P.

Comment: It's the R part of Z. And no, you cannot measure it with an ohmmeter. That one gives you the resistance of the wiring.

Comment: @Janka,For case of pedestal fan/ceiling fan rated 230/240vac, 80 watts..then R=V2/P ,it will be Z? OR R?  Secondly if i measure with ohmeter,then it will be correct R value of fan motor?

Comment: @Janka, I need t refernece somewhre in my report about vaule of indcutance quoted above..Can you share source or link etc that i can reference in my reportplease?

Comment: It was *rough values*, so I cited my own memory. Sorry.

Comment: Thankyou very much sir@Janka